# Console in Eclipse Helios for Java not updating when I edit a class

Tags: java, eclipse, console, helios

I am using Eclipse Helios for Java. Everything was working fine until recently. The problem is the console output is not updating whenever I edit the class that I am running.

E.g. If this was my class

```
public class mainExercise {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("show text");
    }

}
```

If it's the first time I open eclipse, then it will print out in the console (show text). However, if I try to edit it by let's say changing "show text" to "show text edited" and run it, the console still prints out (show text) which should be (show text edited) since I have changed it. I am still new to eclipse so I do not know what happened. Detailed explanation would be very helpful as to what have caused this and how I could fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are saving your changes before running. If you are, maybe you could try and do a rebuild of your source.

Comment: It's working now when I tried to save it first and then run it. I was just wondering because I have done this editing many times before and whenever I click Run, it updates the console right away so I assume that Run also saves the changes before executing. Now, I have to save it first before clicking Run. Although, now I just have to save it first, was there anything that I accidentally changed in the settings that's why clicking Run does not automatically save my changes anymore?

Comment: @mike26: Glad it worked. In my case, I get a pop-up saying if I want to safe my changes first. I also have a checkbox which when ticked will automatically save the changes. I use Eclipse occasionally, but sometimes it seems that things like changing workspaces affects, or resets, the previous settings.

Comment: I just find it odd that it's behavior suddenly changed even though I do not recall changing anything in the settings related to it. Thanks anyway

Comment: @mike26: No worries. P.S. Please consider marking answers to your questions. This will show as a statistic whenever you ask questions. Depending on the value of this statistic, people will be either encouraged or discouraged to answer any future questions you might have.

Comment: Sure. This is my first time to use the site. Could you tell me what you mean by marking the answer? Is this the button where it says "Answer Your Question" and I just have to put there the answer? Thanks

Comment: @mike26: Under the scores there should be a 'Very Good Mark', just tick it and the answer will be marked as accepted.

Comment: @mike26 I wonder how eclipse permitted you to run the program/ build it before you save a file . It would have thrown a pop up asking to save the class.

Comment: @Meenakshi: Before there were popups that tells me to select the resources to save. Recently however, whenever I edit a few lines and click Run, console updates without the popup anymore. That was of course until the console was not updating anymore

Comment: @mike26 Hope you dont have a problem now ..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project and then rebuild it .